# Is there a way to make MessageBox not freeze the application?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm currently experimenting around with message boxes using the Windows.h module  in C++ and I'm curious if there is a way to make the function not hang/freeze the application.

I tried using the MessageBox function and it just hangs/freezes the application until there is user input to the messagebox

Comment: You should show a [mcve]. MessageBox should not freeze your app main window if your code is correct.

Comment: The purpose of a MessageBox is often to provide exactly the behaviour you describe.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do when you pop up that box?  We're just shooting in the dark here.

Comment: The application should not hang or freeze when MessageBox is used as the message pump will continue to dispatch messages. If it's hanging there is likely something else that you are doing to cause it.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious  What is being described is that the dialog popped up by `MessageBox()` grabs focus for all input for that application, so the application's other windows can't process events.   I've seen plenty of users incorrectly describe - like here - that as "freezing the application" when they can't do anything in another window of the application until they find the message box (which may be shown behind another window) and close it.  But, as I noted in a previous comment, all that is documented behaviour of `MessageBox()`.

Comment: @Peter `MessageBox()` doesn't *"grab focus"*. It rather disables its owner window, so input won't reach it. The owner window will still process events as usual, such as timers or repaint requests. If a message box is indeed hidden behind another window, clicking on its (inactive) owner window will bring both the owner window and message box to the foreground, with the message box flashing. What you are describing isn't standard Windows behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Windows API function [`MessageBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox) will create a modal dialog box, which means that the owner window gets disabled and the function will only return as soon as the dialog box is closed.

If you don't want the owner window to get disabled and want the function to return immediately, you should instead create a [modeless dialog box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/about-dialog-boxes#modeless-dialog-boxes) using the functions [`CreateDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winuser/nf-winuser-createdialoga) or [`CreateDialogIndirect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winuser/nf-winuser-createdialogindirecta).

Comment: Hi, thank you so much!
I've read the examples on the microsoft website but I just don't understand anything at all
Are there any other resources you can provide?

Comment: @changeno: I am unaware of any resources that are better than the official Microsoft documentation.

Comment: In addition to the official Microsoft documentation, I (and many others) have been a longtime fan of **Programming Windows** by Charles Petzold.

Answer (score 1):

Another option besides using CreateDialog would be to create a secondary thread and use MessageBox with a NULL hWnd argument.